# ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'RL'

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, seaborn, correlation

I am trying to plot a heatmap from CSV data, but this is the Value Error I get

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import seaborn as sns
```

I upload data from my desktop

```
train = pd.read_csv("Desktop/House Prices/train.csv")

train.head()
```

Trying to plot a heatmap from corr

```
plt.figure(figsize = (20,10))

sns.heatmap(train.corr().abs(), annot = True)
```

And this is the error detail

> ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'RL'

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The error message "could not convert string to float" literally means that the string cannot be converted to a float. In this case, the error is occurring because **you are trying to calculate the correlation of a column that contains strings.**

Comment: I'am trying to calculate correlation between a characteristic with the price, how can I solve that?

Comment: It seems that you need to ask a question, not demand a lecture. Be sure to read the next notification as well.  : [mre]

Answer (score 0):

Since pandas 2.0.0 it should contain `corr(numeric_only=True)`. That solved the error.